# Passing Dynamic Array to function

Tags: c++, linker-errors

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is an undefined reference/unresolved external symbol error and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix)

I am passing a dynamic array of integers to a function and I can't get it to work.

```
int * tempP1;

tempP1 = new int [numP1+1];
```

Call:

```
Polynomial P1(numP1, tempP1);
```

Prototype:

```
Polynomial(int tempNum, int * tempPoly);
```

Function:

```
Polynomial::Polynomial(tempNum, int *tempPoly)
```

Error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "Polynomial::Polynomial(int, int*)", referenced from:
     _main in ccDOuaGg.o
  "Polynomial::~Polynomial()", referenced from:
     _main in ccDOuaGg.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Any help would be much appreciated :)

Comment: baah, it's the problem with arrays, not with externals @Luchian

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz what arrays? The problem is that the constructor/destructor aren't implemented.

Comment: In the definition of the `Polynomial` constructor you are missing the type for the first argument, copy-paste error?

Comment: "passing a dynamic array of integers to a function" using C-style pointers. Meh.

Comment: See answer - http://stackoverflow.com/a/12574403/673730

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the problem. I was compiling this program wrong way.